# Android.view.InflateException: Class not found manifest

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created an android project using ML kit to detect eye region using a custom model.
My problem is in the activity_main.xml
I have two imageView ( one for clicking and the other image to show the prediction of landmarks of eye region ).
I can't see the image and when I try to see error, I got an exception:

> android.view.InflateException: Class not found manifest   at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:222)   at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:139)   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1291)   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1266)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:338)   at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:672)   at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:189)   at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:172)   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:72)   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)

I tried to execute the app, it works but I need to correct this error in the layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_open"
            android:layout_width="117dp"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="156dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.015"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="258dp"
            android:layout_height="211dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_open"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.663"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/image000880" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I click on DrawbleInflater.java, I see many errors.

[image: Errors]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Looks like the manifest got mixed up with the drawables, at some point. Have you tried Cleaning/Rebuilding, Invalidate Caches/Restart, and all that?

Comment: I tried to Invalidate Caches/Restart and nothing has changed, the error persists